# Different nvidia-settings in ubuntu and debian

Tags: xorg, nvidia, gui, gpu, bumblebee

Why in ubuntu (on the top) I've all those entries, while in debian (below) I have a lot fewer? I installed nvidia drivers in ubuntu through gui and in debian through `apt install nvidia-driver`.

In debian I've also same problems and maybe this has to do with `nvidia-settings`.

Indeed installing the drivers for my Nvidia GeForce 950m,the screen sporadically does graphical glitches. These consist of flickering, until I move the mouse abruptly.

I also installed `bumblebee` to try to improve the situation, but nothing changes and not even in nvidia-settings what I need appears.

Tried also to use `nvidia-xconf`, but nothing.

[image]

Comment: And the entries are ...?

Comment: I'm sorry, now I have added the image.

Comment: No idea, you could ask here as well: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148